# How to convert an existing design from USB Mini/Micro to use USB Type-C connector?

Tags: usb, usb-device

What does it convert a design from USB Mini or Micro connector to a USB type-C connector?

To have a more specific question, take for example FTDI Basic (schematic below) which is USB/Serial converter based on FTDI232RL and has a USB Mini connector. Converting this design a USB Micro connector is trivial, just rewiring the 4 connections to the USB Micro connector. What about a USB Type C connector, is it just a clever rewiring? Does it requires additional ICs and functionality to be type C compatible?

All I care about is modifying my existing custom PCB designs to have a functional USB type C connector. Having additional Type C features such as higher speed are non goal. Also, I am not looking for an off the shelf Type C USB/Serial converter but am more interested in converting existing designs to Type C. This is for a hobby/one-of/open-source designs if it matters.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FT232 is full-speed (12mbps) USB device, so you can't possibly take any advantage of Type-C high-speed connector.

To make your FT232 design with Type-C receptacle, all you need is to wire your D+/D- to **PAIR** of D+/D- pins on Type-C (to **both pairs** in parallel) receptacle, and **pull down both CC1 and CC2 pins** to ground with 5.1k resistors.

Comment: Thanks Ali. What about power and ground, connect in the same way to all +5V and GND pins respectively?

Comment: @user1139880, yes, all four grounds and all four VBUS must be connected as usual.